# How to find who have view my profile?

Tags: support, profile-page

I find that there are more than 50 views in one day. It is ridiculous. How can I find out  who have view my profile

Comment: It ain't ridiculous. As an aside, visits to your own profile sometimes get counted as views by the software.

Comment: I had not looked at your profile, but now you have me curious.

Answer (score 7):

You can't. Besides, your profile is meant for viewing. Usually a surge in views means that you participated or were mentioned (directly or indirectly) in a popular thread. You could check and see if something you did seems somewhat popular.

> Besides, there is a rumor that when you hit 1,000,000 profile views you get a free unicorn. So more views are great!

Comment: @robjohn: "again"? :-)

Comment: I have never made something popular.50 views in a day for me is unbelievable.

Comment: @PENGTENG: You may have commented or answered something which was mentioned somewhere; or that was made popular by someone else.

Comment: @PENGTENG: and even this question will net you some profile views.

Comment: Thanks! Do I have right to make a proposal that the website should  add this new feature? : )

Comment: @PENGTENG: Sure. Just post a new meta thread describing the feature and explaining why you think it is good, don't forget to use the [feature-request] tag. Be forewarned, if you ask for a list of visitors to your profile you are likely to be encountered by a barrage of downvotes. These **only** reflect that people disagree that such feature is useful.

Comment: I'd be one of the first to object against profile views by a particular user being visible...

Comment: @J.M. Have you ever used Google Analytics for your own website? We can find many useful and interesting data in GA. It's useful for some people while others may think it's useless. Everyone has their own right to choose to use or not use that feature for their own website. We also have the same right to choose to use that feature on our own profile here.

Comment: @Peng, It's useful, sure. Me, I prefer privacy over utility. I don't need other people knowing all the things I'm looking at.

Comment: @PENG: It should be allowed for a user to be invisible then. If we're listing profile visits, the next thing we'll list upvotes and then downvotes...

Comment: @J.M. If you do not like leaving footprint after viewing others profile, you can turn it off and at the same time you can not find out who has viewed your file. It's fair. It will not disturb you and other people have their own right to choose use or not. No one can force you to and you can not force others : )

Comment: @AsafKaragila 1) Actually, people who give downvotes always leave a comment. It's visible too. 2) If someone like to show their names while give a upvotes, I think it's a stronger way to show "trust" or "approvement" than just showing a number of upvotes.3) People will consider their reputations when they give upvotes or downvotes. It will result in more reliable votes. 4)In addition, it will definitely provide more opportunities for us to communicate. 5) Everyone has their own right to leave footprint or not. It depends on you but you cannot ban others to do so.

Comment: This is a giant waste of time.

Comment: @TheChaz: I'm glad you took the time to let us know.

Comment: My pleasure, @Asaf!